# How to store hour datepart in SQL in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns: Customer_ID, which is a string, identifying each client and Time_id: a string with 14 characters, identifying timestamp of a transaction. Example:

```
Customer_id; Time_id
12345; 20140703144504
```

I want to be able to use datediff in hours datepart, but I can´t seem to be able to convert time_id properly. I use the following query:

```
update transation_table
set time_id= (
convert(timestamp, time_id)
)
```

It works, but removes hours datepart, which is what I need. For day datepart I can do it, converting to datetime. How can I keep in the table the hh?

edit: I´m running MS SQL Server 2014.

best regards

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: what kind of timestamp is this? where do you generate it? Ah now that I look at it, that is no timestamp! ;) That looks like just a normal datetime value 2014-07-03 14:45:04 where you just stripped off the `-` and `:`

Comment: Why are you not storing this data in a column of an appropriate type in the first place?

Comment: You´re right, bad use of words!:) I don´t know how it was generated. That´s correct, it is a datetime value, but I need it to have the formal definitions of time to use datediff, If i´m not mistaken.  Like I said,  for the day datepart it works fine, and datediff too. When I used it for day datepart I stripped it from hh-mm-ss, using left command.

Comment: since the format you have those "timestamps" saved in probably wont change in the next 7000 years you can use `STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF('20140703144504', 5, 0, '-'), 8, 0, '-'), 11, 0, ' '), 14, 0, ':'), 17, 0, ':')` to transform it into a standardized date format (like `2014-07-03 14:45:04`) that can then easily be converted or worked on via `DATEPART` to determine hour part for example.

Comment: I see. Thanks for helping me out. SpectralGhost and beargle´s answers are both very good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the convert and string concatenation below, you can use DATEPART on the resulting value.

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(
    Customer_id VARCHAR(50),
    Time_id VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @tmp
    SELECT '12345','20140703144504'

select
    *,CONVERT(DATETIME,
        SUBSTRING(Time_id,5,2) + '/' +
        SUBSTRING(Time_id,7,2) + '/' +
        SUBSTRING(Time_id,1,4) + ' ' +
        SUBSTRING(Time_id,9,2) + ':' +
        SUBSTRING(Time_id,11,2) + ':' +
        SUBSTRING(Time_id,13,2)
        ,101
    )
from @tmp
```

Comment: If you're going to mangle a string into a format that can be converted into a `datetime`, please, at the very least *either* mangle it into an unambiguous format, *or* at least specify a *style* parameter in the `CONVERT` call. This currently does neither and may end up generating a datetime that is either the 7th of March or the 3rd of July.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) to get a string representation of the value in a [supported format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) (ODBC canonical in the Date and Time styles chart), then use [TRY_CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) to return an actual datetime value:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME,
                   FORMAT(CAST('20140703144504' AS BIGINT),
                          '####-##-## ##:##:##'),
                   120);
```

This requires SQL Server 2012+.

As mentioned elsewhere, the data should be stored in a single [datetime2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) column, or paired [date](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) and [time](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) columns. The above functions can be used to help convert existing data to the new column(s).